# Using a dataframe to format the style of another dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-apply, pandas-styles

I have one pandas dataframe that I want to style the format based on the values of another dataframe of the same shape/size.  I'm trying to use applymap.

Here's an example:

```py
t1= pd.DataFrame({'x':['A','B','C'], 'y':['C','B','D']})
t2= pd.DataFrame({'x':[0.3,0.2,0.7], 'y':[1,0.3,2]})

def color_cells(s, threshold=0.5):
    if s > threshold:
        return 'color:{0}; font-weight:bold'.format('red')
    else:
        return ''

#Tried
t1.style.applymap(t2.applymap(color_cells))
```

Ideally in t1 where the corresponding cells in t2>0.5 then the values in t1 are in 'red-bold'.

However, I'm unsure what pattern I should use to get this desired effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were almost there, you need to use the apply function with a lambda instead to iterate through the cells.

`t1.style.apply(lambda x: t2.applymap(color_cells), axis=None)`